# How can I use replacedlg.ui in mainwindow.cpp?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, qt-designer, qtgui

I have written a project which includes a `mainwindow` and a `replacedlg.ui`. I want to use `replacedlg.ui` in  `mainwindow.cpp`.

I'd like to write things like `ui->button` in `mainwindow.cpp`, but I can't.

Who can help me make this work?

[The whole project is here.](https://github.com/konalo-X/myqt/tree/master/wordpad1)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You're just breaking encapsulation here. You should write methods in your `replacedlg` class that will do what you need to do instead.

Comment: @thuga i will accept you advice  if i know and i have better.but  have not.idonot know  how to  send the text i  have input  into the  lineedit which in replacedlg.so  what's  kind of method i  use  can  send the text to mainwindow?

Comment: You can emit a signal in your `replaceDlg` class, that contains the `QString` as a parameter. Connect this signal to a slot in your `MainWindow` class.

Comment: @thuga is there  any  better way ? Or  can you  give me  a  tiny sample.just about  a mainwindow with Textedit use  pure  code . A  dialog.ui with a   Lineedit  .then creat a signal to send lineedit's input to  the  textedit in  mainwindow?

Comment: @thuga can you give me you Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to share the `ui` variable between classes. It is bad design. Instead add methods in your classes which will let you do what you need to do.

In your case where you want to send the text of your line edit from `replaceDlg` class to your `MainWindow` class, you should use signals and slots. Here is an example:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        setCentralWidget(&text_edit);
    }
public slots:
    void addText(const QString &text)
    {
        text_edit.append(text);
    }
private:
    QTextEdit text_edit;
};

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QDialog(parent)
    {
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
        QPushButton *send_button = new QPushButton("Send");
        layout()->addWidget(&line_edit);
        layout()->addWidget(send_button);
        connect(send_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Dialog::sendButtonClicked);
    }
signals:
    void sendText(const QString &text);
private slots:
    void sendButtonClicked()
    {
        emit sendText(line_edit.text());
        accept();
    }
private:
    QLineEdit line_edit;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    Dialog d;
    QObject::connect(&d, &Dialog::sendText, &w, &MainWindow::addText);
    w.show();
    d.show();    
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```